# travis-ci - ssh-add asking for my passphrase

Tags: linux, ssh, continuous-integration, debian, travis-ci

I am working on a continuous integration with Travis CI.
This is my configuration:

```
before_install:
  - echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n" > ~/.ssh/config
  - echo -e $id_rsa.pub > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
  - echo -e $id_rsa > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  - sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
  - sudo chmod 644 ~/.ssh/config
  - eval `ssh-agent -s`
  - ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  ...

$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Enter passphrase for /home/travis/.ssh/id_rsa:
```

On the ssh-add step, it ask me the passphrase and it's stop the deployment. I have tested with an other ssh key without passphrase but it don't fix my issue.

I have tested lot of solution like `yes $MY_PASSWORD | ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` or `echo "$MY_PASSWORD" | ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` but it don't works.

I have added to my .ssh/config (you can see it in my config):

```
Host *
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

isn't it supposed to make it don't ask me the passphrase ?

Maybe someone have an idea ?
Thanks :)

Comment: *"`StrictHostKeyChecking no` ... isn't it supposed to make it don't ask me the passphrase?"* - No. `StrictHostKeyChecking` is the SSH equivalent to public key pinning in other protocols like HTTPS. It has nothing to do with remote login credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using encrypted private key (which is good), but it needs the passphrase (which is bad for scripting). There are several possibilities you can proceed:

- Remove the passphrase from the key and use it unencrypted (less secure)

  ```
  ssh-keygen -p -P "old_passphrase" -N "" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  ```
- Use `sshpass` tool to unlock the key (storing the passphrase next to the key in the script basically defeats the security of encrypted key)

  ```
  sshpass -p passphrase ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  ```

Comment: there is maybe something wrong with my manipulation... i have tested both of your command who looks good to resolve my issue but it say to me "bad passphrase" so i don't understand because in local on my computer it works.... i missed something with ssh keys on travis I think... i have created another ssh key with no password in local to put it on travis and it says to me "bad passphrase" too.. strange..

Comment: Please, clearly explain what have you done, what modifications did you made to the above "script", how did you create the old key or the new one.

Comment: let forget my new key, i use for the moment just the old one, wich is my current local key on my personnal computer. I had copied the content of .ssh/id_rsa and .ssh/id_rsa.pub in two environment variable on travis-ci.org settings panel ($id_rsa and $id_rsa.pub). I did the same with my passphrase in $passphrase. in the script I posted (the before_script part, before the ss-add command) I added "sshpass -p $passphrase ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa". It says to me "bad password". I tried the same command on local on my computer without environment variables and it works with the same keys.

Comment: `- echo -e $id_rsa > ~/.ssh/id_rsa` sounds wrong. The id is multiline and I don't think it is correctly handled with `echo`

Comment: I had tested with passphrase hardcoded in my script and it says to me bad passphrase too. After verify my keys i have something that could be help :  cat -e ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

-----BEGIN.pub$ and the file finishes here.

Comment: [SSH says "bad passphrase" to quite anything](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2522). It is known bug. The file is written wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had resolved my problem.
I had different problem in basic utilisation of environment variables and echo.

- My environment variables names were not good. "$id_rsa.pub" in travis was interpreted by $id_rsa . ".pub" so it added some wrong characters to my content. I renamed it to id_rsa_pub.
- I forget to transform " " in "\ " and newlines by "\n" and with travis and his environment variables, you must write "\\n" instead of just "\n".

My issue was in part because bad ssh files, and because I use a rsa key with password. In my case it's not important to have a password so i deleted it.
For that i use the answer of jakuje. My ssh key is now installed correctly in each builds.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
before_install:
    - [...]
    - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - chmod 700 local-ssh-askpass
    - eval `ssh-agent -s`
    - DISPLAY=1 SSH_ASKPASS_REQUIRE=force SSH_ASKPASS=./local-ssh-askpass ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa < /dev/null
```

Don't forget to set :

- DISPLAY=1 to force local ask script
- do redirect input from /dev/null
- any echo passphrase from local-ssh-askpass script